# Drop overlapping rows on outer join in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two dataframe and throw away the overlapping rows on index (id)

```
dfA

id     group       size
001     B           S
002     C           S
003     A           XL

dfB
id     group       size
004     A           M
001     B           S
```

My attempt:

```
outer_join = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on='id', how='outer')
outer_join.loc[~dfA.id.isin(outer_join.id)]
```

My expected output:

```
id     group       size
001     B           S
002     C           S
003     A           XL
004     A           M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = outer_join.loc[~dfA.id.isin(outer_join.id)]

df.drop_duplicates()
```

[Reference](https://riptutorial.com/pandas/example/26077/select-distinct-rows-across-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Use `combine_first`:

```
print (dfA.set_index("id").combine_first(dfB.set_index("id")))

   group size
id           
1      B    S
2      C    S
3      A   XL
4      A    M
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
newdf = pd.concat([dfA, dfB]).groupby('id').head(1)
```